# validates vs db check up in rails 3.1 for field presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In rails 3.1, we can validate presence of a field in model with:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

In db migration file, we also can do

```
t.string :name, :null => false
```

It seems that validates checks the data integrity before saving which is better. However db check up only happens during the saving process which may have started actual saving before aborting. Is validates in model better? Thanks so much.

Comment: Validations on models are generally enough, though the rails guides go into why you may want to use database constraints as well. I'd recommend giving this section of the guides a read. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#why-use-validations-questionmark

Answer (score 1):

Writing validations in models is generally a good practice as your it lot more maintainable, can be changed easily as and when you need it and also having all the core login in 1 place is good.

When you write such things only at the db level, writing test cases becomes a problem and when you get back to your later you may not realise that you have written such "logic" in the db level.

Actually, I even write my "default" values at the model (although this can be debated upon). The reason for this is that having a default option is a business login and hence needs to go at the model level.

For the above reason, its a good practice to write such code at the model level.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I stumbled across it today and I think the answer is the same whether you are using Rails 3.1 or Rails 6: **it depends**.

Both database constraints and model validations exist for a reason. In addition to those two, I think it's also worth considering where client-side checks fit in.

My short answer is:

- always write model validations
- in most cases back them up with database constraints
- sometimes add on client-side checks

As with most things, stick with these simple rules while you're learning and you won't go far wrong. Later on you can start to break these rules, once you know why you're breaking them.

I wrote up my longer ("it depends") answer (and my reasons for the rules above) in a [post on my blog](https://www.matt17r.com/2019/05/29/validating-data-in.html).